# How does SuperUser/StackExchange survive?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I was looking over Stack Exchange to see something about donations or another system that provides financial sustainability to Super User, and I didn't find anything. Stack Exchange must require a huge infrastructure, such as computers, bandwith, backups, database servers, etc.

So, how does Stack Exchange survive? Are there any sponsors? Besides moderators, who maintains the sites?

Comment: I forgot to tell that I didint find any ads on any stackexchange forums as well...

Comment: Well I've never found a forum around here either :P

Comment: StackOverFlow may be as a part of community organizations in US... MAYBE! So get fees from government. Or worse maybe sell IDEAS ... WOW!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a post on Meta Stack Overflow explaining [Stack Exchange's business model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model).

Donations have been suggested before, but have always been rejected, for various reasons.

Stack Exchange is maintained by the [SE Team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team), most of which work remotely.

In early 2011, SE received [an influx of venture capital money](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/) as well.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your revealing response.